# How can I turn this line of objective-C code into Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

```
@protocol YozioMetaDataCallbackable <NSObject>

/**
 * implement this method to handle the callback from new install or deeplink.
 *
 * @param targetViewControllerName - the target view controller that you configured in Yozio Web Console.
 * @param metaData - the meta data passed to your app.
 */
- (void) onCallbackWithTargetViewControllerName:(NSString *)targetViewControllerName
                                    andMetaData:(NSDictionary *)metaData;

@end
```

I tried subclassing it to Swift:

```
class YozioCaller: NSObject , YozioMetaDataCallbackable {
    func onCallbackWithTargetViewControllerName(targetViewControllerName: NSString!, andMetaData metaData: NSDictionary!){
    }
}
```

But it states that it doesn't conform.

Comment: Have you tried `YozioCaller: NSObject, YozioMetaDataCallbackable`?

Comment: @ThomasKilian, just updated code. Still doesn't work.

Comment: I'm actually confused why in the OBJ-C code, the method has "andMetaData" and "metaData".

Comment: Shouldn't the 2nd parameter be `andMetaData`?

Comment: @Antonio tried ```andMetaData```, but still doesn't conform. What is "metaData"?

Comment: The first is the signature (you see outside) and the 2nd is the name used inside the method. You could also try removing the `!` (just guessing here)

Comment: Tried removing the ```!```, still no good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In swift, use String for NSString and [ NSObject: AnyObject ] for NSDictionary.

```
func
onCallbackWithTargetViewControllerName(
    targetViewControllerName: String?
,   andMetaData: [ NSObject: AnyObject ]?
){
}
```